# How to validate an IP address using regular expression in java?

Tags: java

I have an IP address for which I want to define a regular expression to write it in its proper format. Please suggest a way in which I can achieve this.

Comment: public static boolean isValidIP(String ipAddr){
         
        Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})$");
        Matcher mtch = ptn.matcher(ipAddr);
        return mtch.find();
    }
This will work

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one :

```
^(([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d)\.){3}([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d)$
```

Comment: Does not even catch all ip addresses: `::1`